# VBA-Copy and paste special based upon a drop down selection using a command button

Tags: excel, vba

I'm wondering if you can assist me with my query, i'm a complete VBA amateur.

I'm trying to write a piece of VBA to copy and paste values in a range of cells into a separate worksheet starting in a specific column when I click a command button.

Picture this

I have my master sheet that looks up data and returns a load of values against a timeline running from Mar-20 to Dec-20

I also have a drop down, that will allow me to select a new month Jul-20 say, I then want to click a button that will copy and paste this data into a new timeline, on a separate sheet, starting at the month selected in the drop down.

I have taken some code I created for something else and amended it to try and get it to work for this.

Any help would be appreciated.  Ignore the else manual entry, that's a legacy from its previous iteration.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim controlRng, nRng As Range
    Set controlRng = Range("AD12")  ' This the range of cells which I have defined to be my dropdown cells.
    Set nRng = Intersect(controlRng, Target)  ' Find out if any of the dropdown cells have been changed
    lastrow = Sheets("Planning").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    If nRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub  ' None of the dropdown cells have changed so no need to do anything further

    If Target.Value = "Apr-20" Then
        Range("AH10:AH30").Copy
        Sheets("Planning").Range("C" & lastrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues ' Copy and paste values to next available rows in destination sheet

    ElseIf Target.Value = "May-20" Then
          Range("AH10:AH30").Copy
          Sheets("Planning").Range("D" & lastrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues ' Copy and paste values to next available rows in destination sheet


    ElseIf Target.Value = "Jun-20" Then
          Range("AH10:AH30").Copy
          Sheets("Planning").Range("E" & lastrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues ' Copy and paste values to next available rows in destination sheet 

    ElseIf Target.Value = "Jul-20" Then
         Range("AH10:AH30").Copy
         Sheets("Planning").Range("F" & lastrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues ' Copy and paste values to next available rows in destination sheet

    ElseIf Target.Value = "Aug-20" Then
          Range("AH10:AH30").Copy
         Sheets("Planning").Range("G" & lastrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues ' Copy and paste values to next available rows in destination sheet
    Else
        'Manual entry
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is te question (you didn't ask one)? What is wrong with your code? Note that `Worksheet_Change` is an event. That means this code runs automaticall on a cell change (not on a button click). • Also this might fail if `Target` is a range and not a single cell, so you need to change `Target.Value` into `controlRng` in your `If` statements. • And finally recent Excel versions have more than `65536` rows. So it should be `Range("A" & Rows.Count)`.

Comment: Good point, I didn't ask a question. oops. The above code I pasted doesn't work. It isn't copying and pasting any values.

Comment: i will try the amendments you have suggested to see if it works., how would i get it to work on a button click, please.

Comment: Did you debug it? See [Excel Easy - Debugging](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html). Put a breakpoint in the beginning and have a look if the event triggers on a cell change. Then go through your code step by step using F8 to see which statements get excecuted. To use a button please read [Assign a macro to a Form or a Control button](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/assign-a-macro-to-a-form-or-a-control-button-d58edd7d-cb04-4964-bead-9c72c843a283)

Comment: Right I've got the code working. to some extent. There were some errant lines in there that were giving me errors, so I removed them.  And the If statement now works as i was using text to match against a custom MMM-YY cell value. So i formatted the cells to text. However i have a new issue where it doesn't look for the next free row and input data it just copies over the last data.

Comment: New issue means new question here on SO (only 1 question per post). So you should open up a new question with your actual code according to [ask] and ask your new question there.